# Power of a test for equivalency

Tags: anova, sample-size, statistical-power, equivalence

I want to know the power of a test I am conducting. Data was collected from three drugs to investigate equivalency of these three drugs for treating a disease. The data has already been collected so I want to know what the power is. Drug one has a sample of 26 people, mean response of u1 and SD1. Drug 2 has sample of 16, u2, SD2 and drug 3 sample size of 12, mean response u3, SD3.

How do I assess what the power is for pairwise comparisons between these drugs? I want to know probability of not detecting a difference between groups from these data, don't I? How do I assess how reliable this dataset is for demonstrating 'equivalency'?

Comment: There no test for real equivalency, which would require an infinite sample size to demonstrate.  There are ways to assess non-inferiority and simple Bayesian assessments of the probability of similarity.  For the latter you define a similarity region and compute the posterior probability that the unknown treatment effect is in that region.

Comment: Perhaps some of the questions using the non-inferiority tag might help you get a better grip on the issues here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of ​​a “true equivalence test” is somewhat paradoxical. In statistical hypothesis testing (in the frequentest paradigm), it is important  to understand that we never "accept" a null hypothesis; we only "fail to reject" it. Regarding equivalency testing, the objective is to demonstrate that there is no meaningful difference between groups. This is inherently difficult because proving a negative (i.e., proving something does not exist) is a challenging proposition in statistics.

To declare definitively that two treatments are equivalent would require considering all possible sources of variation and all possible patients requiring an infinite sample size. Any test performed on finite samples can only limit differences between groups to a certain extent and can never completely eliminate the possibility that differences exist.

Instead of testing for true equivalency, what is often done in practice is a non-inferiority test. Here, the goal is to demonstrate that a new treatment (or drug) is not worse than an existing treatment by more than a pre-specified margin, $ \Delta $. This is a more achievable goal with finite samples. The hypotheses for such a test are typically:

$ H_0: \mu_1 - \mu_2 \leq -\Delta $ (i.e., Drug 1 is inferior by at least $ \Delta $)

$ H_a: \mu_1 - \mu_2 > -\Delta $

In the context of assessing similarity between treatments, a Bayesian approach would involve defining a "similarity region" which delineates the range of differences between treatments that are deemed to be practically equivalent. Then, using prior information and the collected data, one computes the posterior probability that the true, but unknown, treatment effect lies within this similarity region. A high posterior probability would suggest strong evidence for the treatments being similar, while a low probability would suggest otherwise.